# How to properly test this component I made, with react testing library?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-testing-library

I need to test the functionality of the component that I made. This component is editing the users that I fetch from API, but I send these users to this component via Link from react router which is another component.

This is how my EditPage component looks like:

```
const EditPage = () => {
  let { id, name, email, status } = useParams();
  const [newName, setNewName] = useState(name);
  const [newEmail, setNewEmail] = useState(email);
  const [newStatus, setNewStatus] = useState("");

  const updateName = (e) => {
    setNewName(e.target.value);
  };

  const updateEmail = (e) => {
    setNewEmail(e.target.value);
  };

  const updateStatus = (e) => {
    setNewStatus(e.target.value);
  };

  const updateData = () => {
    axios.put(
      `https://gorest.co.in/public/v1/users/${id}`,
      {
        name: newName === "" ? name : newName,
        email: newEmail === "" ? email : newEmail,
        status: newStatus === "" ? status : newStatus,
      },
      {
        headers: {
          Authorization:
            "Bearer my token goes here, but for privacy it is not here",
        },
      }
    );
  };

  return (
    <EditContainer>
      <EditTitle data-testid="editpage-title">Edit User</EditTitle>
      <UpdateInputsContainer data-testid="editpage-inputs">
        <NameInputContainer>
          <UpdateInputs
            labelName="Name:"
            placeholder="Insert the name..."
            value={newName}
            onChange={updateName}
          />
        </NameInputContainer>
        <EmailInputContainer>
          <UpdateInputs
            labelName="Email:"
            placeholder="Insert the email..."
            value={newEmail}
            onChange={updateEmail}
          />
        </EmailInputContainer>
        <SelectStatus value={newStatus || status} onChange={updateStatus}>
          <MenuItem value="active">Active</MenuItem>
          <MenuItem value="inactive">Inactive</MenuItem>
        </SelectStatus>
        <ButtonsContainer data-testid="editpage-buttons">
          <Link to="/users">
            <CancelButton variant="outlined" text="CANCEL"></CancelButton>
          </Link>
          <Link to="/users">
            <EditButton
              onClick={updateData}
              variant="filled"
              text="UPDATE"
              data-testid="editpage-updatebutton"
            ></EditButton>
          </Link>
        </ButtonsContainer>
      </UpdateInputsContainer>
    </EditContainer>
  );
};

export default EditPage;
```

Now I have made some tests on my own, but I feel like they are not enough or they are not working at all, this is what I made:

```
const setup = () => {
  render(
    <Router>
      <EditPage />
    </Router>
  );
};

describe("edit page", () => {
  test("renders properly", () => {
    setup();

    expect(screen.getByTestId("editpage-title")).toBeInTheDocument();
    expect(screen.getByTestId("editpage-inputs")).toBeInTheDocument();
    expect(screen.getByTestId("editpage-buttons")).toBeInTheDocument();
  });

  test("changing values of inputs is working and data gets updated", () => {
    setup();

    const nameInput = screen.getByPlaceholderText("Insert the name...");
    const emailInput = screen.getByPlaceholderText("Insert the email...");

    fireEvent.change(nameInput, {
      target: {
        value: "Test",
      },
    });

    fireEvent.change(emailInput, {
      target: {
        value: "test@gmail.com",
      },
    });

    expect(nameInput).toHaveValue("Test");
    expect(emailInput).toHaveValue("test@gmail.com");

    fireEvent.click(screen.getByText("UPDATE"));
  });

  test("cancel button is working", () => {
    setup();

    fireEvent.click(screen.getByText("CANCEL"));
  });
});
```

Does anyone know how to test this component properly, like how to tell that the data was actually updated or how to actually tell that it was not updated to be precise that the cancel button was pressed. If you know how to do this, I would greatly appreciate that.

Comment: For the React software that we develop, we split out the logic from the React components and write tests around the logic itself, we don't write tests on the inputs and outputs of components.  So if you have validation logic for your name & email fields, we test that logic instead.  We structure our component files like this: MyComponent.tsx, MyComponent.logic.ts, MyComponent.connect.ts.  The tsx file will have our JSX for the component, the logic file has all the functions etc, and the connect will have the redux store retrieval logic and types.  Our tests focus on what's in the logic files.

Comment: My point is, unless you have been required to write tests on the component, it's probably better to write your tests against any "code behind" logic instead.  We use jest, and have an 85% code coverage threshold.

Comment: What do you mean by "against code behind logic"?

Comment: Sure, it means that we *assume* the component UI is going to display how we expect because React will do it's thing with the DOM as we expect.  However we still want to test functions that do special behind the scenes things, mock test our apis, and test our action creators for the redux store, etc.    At least that's how our SAAS development team does it.

Comment: Ok, thank you for explanation, but honestly I am still not sure how to implement what you said here in my tests. What I understand is that I maybe need to have some mocked api for my tests, and try to change data of that api with my tests, to mimic real functionality, right?